# Can I have a property (field) and a method inside an object with same name?

Tags: javascript

I have a class like this:

```js
let enabled = false;

class List {
    constructor (...args) {
        this.args = args;
    }
    get Count() {
        if (enabled) {
            let _this = this;

            return () => _this.args.length;            
        }
        
        return this.args.length;
    }
}

let list = new List('a', true, null);

// 'Count' is not a method/function by default
console.log(list.Count); // 3

// do something to enable this flag:
enabled = true;

// 'Count' is a method now
console.log(list.Count()); // 3
```

I want to use both of 2 syntaxes at the same time (no need to enable/disable something).

```
console.log(list.Count); // 3
console.log(list.Count()); // 3
```

Can I do that? And how? Thank you!

Comment: perhaps using a proxy object

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: @robertklep Because I come from C# background and want to know that can I do something in js same to C# syntax or not. I found the answer: Nope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually no such thing as "methods" or "properties" in a JavaScript object. There are only "keys", which are more in line with properties. It's just that some keys store a function as its data and that data can be invoked once accessed by appending `()` on to the result of the key look up. Only keys that store functions will allow for `list.Count()` syntax.

So, no, you can't have two keys with the same identifier, regardless of the data they hold.

But, this goes beyond syntax and relates directly to proper OO design. You distinguish what will use property syntax vs. method syntax by determining what the purpose of the key is. If the key is to store object "state", use property syntax and if the key is to invoke object "behavior", use method syntax because storing "state" and providing "behavior" are the two things that objects do for us in the first place.

Additionally, there are actually no such thing as "classes" in JavaScript either. The keyword and its syntax are there to make classical OO programmers feel more at home, but under the hood, classes do not exist. Only objects and their prototype objects.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that will work, or that you'd want to do something like that.
Take a look at Proxy https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy